# MVC5 Pattern regular expression validation is not working in textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I add any regular expression pattern in MVC for textarea it's not working. When I click on submit button the wrong value is added to database

My View Code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MyEntity.Item, new { @required = "required", @class = "form-control english_only", @placeholder = "Item", @maxlength = "120", @Pattern = @"[^A-Za-z0-9]" })
```

My Model Code:

```
[StringLength(150)]
public string Item{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Why are you using HTML-5 validation attributes instead of MVC built in validation (with `jquery.validate.js)` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)?

Comment: You don't need any experience in `jQuery` - you just add the 2 scripts to your view or layout and add validation attributes to your propery. And HTML-5 validation is client side only and you would need to write more code to get server side validation. And what do your mean _by MVC pattern_ - that is exactly what your NOT doing

Comment: Suggest you read [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: Also, HTML5 `<textarea>` element does not support `pattern` attribute, see allowed attributes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: Use the [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.7) and let MVC generate the appropriate validation code. Browser-side validation is trivial to bypass. You'll have to add the validation to your Model as well otherwise someone could simply use the F12 tools of the browser, curl or Fiddler to make a direct POST with invalid content.

Comment: @Mohammed What kind of validation is not working in textarea for example required,max length,or Pattern else all of these thing....

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM Pattern is not working in textarea

Answer (score 0):

This is just for any other who have this problem...
Based on Developers comments:
`HTML5 <textarea>` element does not support pattern attribute

so the solution is by MVC built in validation (with `jquery.validate.js`) and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)

So this problem solve by change my model to be:

```
[StringLength(150)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "UPRN must be numeric")]
        public string Item{ get; set; }
```

and also include the `jquery.validate.js` in my view or partial view

Ore simply change my html helper to be text box instead of text Area as following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control english_only", @placeholder = "Only english text", @required = "required", @Pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9$@$!%*?&#^-_. +]+$", @title = "please insert english text only", @autocomplete= "off", @maxlength = "120" } })
```

Comment: If your using MVC's built in validation (the correct approach), then adding `new { required = "required", Pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9$@$!%*?&#^-_. +]+$", maxlength = "120" }` is pointless since those attributes are ignored